# How to exclude particular page/node from Drupal 8 cache

Tags: caching, search, drupal-8

I have created a search page for a drupal 8 theme, but the page is cached. Whatever I have inputed for search,  it always give me the result of the first query I input.

How can I exclude the search page from the cached?

Comment: If the page is a view, you can disable caching for the view in the advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drupal 8 [CacheExclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module to exclude the search page url from getting cached.